# Is there a secret parameter for rounding numbers in Excel PowerQuery?

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

Please tell me how to round numbers correctly in Excel PowerQuery?

- Type "0.925" into Excel.
- Play with the toolbar, and **Decrease deimals**, and the number goes to 0.93
- Try a formula: = Round(0.925,2) and you get 0.93

Now try it in PowerQuery

- Amount = 0.925
- Round([Amount],2) = 0.92

What secret parameter must I use to do the calculation correctly?

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjQ1NzU01bM0MlWKjQUA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"RAW Number" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"RAW Number", type number}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Round", each Number.Round([RAW Number],2)),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "FancyRound", each Number.Round([RAW Number], 2, RoundingMode.Up))
in
    #"Added Custom2"
```

So this query above, in Excel doesn't work

But in Power BI it does.

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Answer (score 4):

Power Query defaults to `round to even` for tie-breaking, which is the same as VBA. There are many methods of tie-breaking which have the goal of minimizing bias in the result. Power Query has some of the methods, but by no means all of them.

Excel's default rounding mode is to `Round Away from Zero`

Here is a function which demonstrates the behavior of the various rounding modes, in Excel Power Query:

```
//NAME this query "fnDemoRoundingMode"

(n as number, d as number)=>
   Table.FromColumns(
        {
            {"Away from Zero","Down","To Even","Toward Zero","Up"},
            {Number.Round(n,d,RoundingMode.AwayFromZero),
             Number.Round(n,d,RoundingMode.Down),
             Number.Round(n,d,RoundingMode.ToEven),
             Number.Round(n,d,RoundingMode.TowardZero),
             Number.Round(n,d,RoundingMode.Up)}
        },
            type table[Mode=text, Rounded=number])
```

Here are the results using `0.925` rounded to two digits

```
= fnDemoRoundingMode(0.925,2)
```

[image]

*There are related functions such as `Number.RoundUp` and others which may also be useful in certain circumstances.
And if you are rounding to an Integer, you can try `Int64.From` which also takes the `RoundingMode` arguments and will convert text strings to numbers with an optional culture argument.*

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this is an annoying default.

```
Number.Round([Column1],2, RoundingMode.AwayFromZero)
```

> Returns the result of rounding number to the nearest number. If number
> is null, Number.Round returns null.
>
> By default, number is rounded to the nearest integer, and ties are
> broken by rounding to the nearest even number (using
> RoundingMode.ToEven, also known as "banker's rounding").
>
> However, these defaults can be overridden via the following optional
> parameters.
>
> digits: Causes number to be rounded to the specified number of decimal digits.
> roundingMode: Overrides the default tie-breaking behavior when number is at the midpoint between two potential rounded values (refer
> to RoundingMode.Type for possible values).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/number-round

[image]

Comment: Thanks... I tried all 5 examples ... none of them work. 
To be clear, this is Power Query on Excel, not PowerBI.

Comment: The second line in my answer does exactly what you want. I confirmed it in Excel before posting.

Comment: Number.Round([Column1],2, RoundingMode.AwayFromZero